# XSLT; search through entire xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to look through an entire XML with XSLT, both in 1.0 and 2.0.
The idea is a follows, I want value 1234 from this xml

```
<root>
 <data>test</data>
 <root2>
  <data2>testt</data2>
  <data3>1234</data3>
 </root2>
</root>
```

Point is, the value is in a different place in the xml every time, depending on who delivers the XML. Is it technically possible to look through all XML elements for a specific value?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected result of the transformation?

Comment: So what are the criteria for searching, the element name `data3`?

Comment: The criteria is the value of the element, not the element itself as the value can be in any element. The expected result is to find the value, and based on that value execute certain other actions in the xslt. If the value is not found in the xml at all, the same xml will be returned. I've got that down, except for this issue..

Comment: I am afraid that makes no sense. What are you looking for in the process of "finding the value"? If you already know the value, then why look for it?

Comment: Well, it is trivial to find `//*[. = '1234']`, i.e. any element with the value `1234`.

Comment: I'm looking for a specific value in the xml which contains 2 letters followed by 6 numbers, the contents of this vary per xml. So one xml its in <data1>XX345678</data1> and next xml its in <data2>AA123456</data>. Really want to know if that's possible.

Comment: You're still not being clear. Do you want to return the value, or do you just want to test for its existence?

Comment: Yes, `//*[matches(., '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$')]` selects any element matching the pattern of two ASCII letters A-Z and six digits. `matches` is XPath XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Is there the only "value" in the document that matches your pattern or there might be several "values"?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Only one value should match

Comment: @stunnie:  Please read [ask].  Providing you an answer shouldn't require continuous requests for clarification.  Also, please [edit] your question and consolidate all clarifications added via comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is probably not quite elegant, but it will work for XPath 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:value-of select="//*[not(*)][boolean(number(substring(text(), 3, 6)))][translate(substring(text(), 1, 2), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')='ZZ'][string-length(text())=8]/text()"/>
    </xsl:template >
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test data:

```
<root>
 <data>test</data>
 <root2>
  <data2>testt</data2>
  <data3>XX345678</data3>
 </root2>
</root>
```

Test output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>XX345678
```

Here the only leaf nodes are taken, then we test if the text starts with two letters and ends with 6 digits.